# Inheriting from Dictionary class with tuple as value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class that inherits from Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>.

I need my Value part of the KeyValue pair to be a a Tuple **(int, bool )**

```
 public class IssueRowValidationDictionary :
        Dictionary<string, (int, bool)>
    {
        public IssueRowValidationDictionary() : base() { }

        internal void Add(string issueReference, int rawRowNumber, bool v)
        {
            Add(issueReference, (rawRowNumber, v));
        }
    }
```

In my code there are cases where I need to get the int Value  part  of the dictionary Element

```
                 var intValue = issueRowValidationDictionary['keyRef'].Item1;
```

Is there a more elegant way for Example to create a specific property that will only return the int part of the value. Any suggestions for improvement of my code are welcomed

Comment: Should go on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can name the tuple elements, e.g `Dictionary<string, (int IntVal, bool StringVal)>` and then use the more descriptive `issueRowValidationDictionary['keyRef'].IntVal`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just define a method:

```cs
public int GetIntValue(string key)
{
    return this[key].Item1;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```cs
var intValue = issueRowValidationDictionary.GetIntValue("keyRef");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the tuple by a class with well named properties or write a method like `public int GetIntValue(string key)` (see @srk answer to detail).

Finally, you can define a indexer like :

```cs
public class IntValues
{
    private readonly IssueRowValidationDictionary _datas;

    public IntValues(IssueRowValidationDictionary data)
    {
        _datas = data;
    }

    public int this[string key] => _datas[key].Item1;
}

public class IssueRowValidationDictionary :
    Dictionary<string, (int, bool)>
{
    public IntValues IntValues { get; }

    public IssueRowValidationDictionary() : base()
    { 
        IntValues = new IntValues(this);
    }

    internal void Add(string issueReference, int rawRowNumber, bool v)
    {
        Add(issueReference, (rawRowNumber, v));
    }
}
```

You can use like :

```cs
var intValue = issueRowValidationDictionary.IntValues["keyRef"];
```

Bonus : you can mask the `IntValues` class with a interface.